# Laravel join query not working when passing a variable

Tags: php, laravel

I want to execute a join statment in laravel by passing a php varaiable,Bit its not working when passing a varibale. Following is my code

```
  $loc_services = Clinic::select('*')
    ->join('locations', 'locations.clinicID', '=', 'clinics.clinicID')
    ->join('location_services', 'location_services.locationID', '=', 'locations.locationID')
    ->join('services', 'services.serviceID', '=', $services_id)
    ->get();
```

I tried to execute it as statment and got the following

```
select * from `clinics` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`clinicID` = `clinics`.`clinicID` inner join `location_services` on `location_services`.`locationID` = `locations`.`locationID` inner join `services` on `services`.`serviceID` = `10`
```

When i directly executed it in phpmyadmin it returns fllowing error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '10' in 'on clause', i found that error is triggering because `10` is inside  `''` quotes, how can i execute this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `$services_id` in where cloud not in `join on`

```
$loc_services = Clinic::select('*')
->join('locations', 'locations.clinicID', '=', 'clinics.clinicID')
->join('location_services', 'location_services.locationID', '=', 'locations.locationID')
->join('services', 'services.serviceID', '=', 'clinics.services_id')//service_id column in Clinic
->where('services.serviceID',$services_id)    
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in join will be treated as column. If you want to join the column with a specific value, you can use closure like this:

```php
$loc_services = Clinic::select('*')
    ->join('locations', 'locations.clinicID', '=', 'clinics.clinicID')
    ->join('location_services', 'location_services.locationID', '=', 'locations.locationID')
    ->join('services', function($join) use ($service_id) {
         $join->where('services.serviceID', $service_id);
      })
    ->get();
```

The Raw sql will be:

```sql
inner join `services` on `services`.`serviceID` = 10
```